# Prawn: Formatting a bounding box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am a programming and Ruby novice, trying to use Prawn to generate a PDF. I am following the Prawn manual but am having problems with putting text in a bounding box. Here is my code, which mostly comes from the Prawn manual... :

```
  pdf.bounding_box([200, pdf.cursor - 100], :width => 200, :height => 100) do
      pdf.text "Just your regular bounding box"
      pdf.transparent(0.5) { pdf.stroke_bounds }
  end
```

If I remove this line:  `pdf.transparent(0.5) { stroke_bounds }`,
The code will work but I can't see the text box. What do I need to change?

Comment: You didn't explain what happens when you try to run that code as-is.  What are you trying to do, and what result are you getting instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the transparent formatting and simply say:

```
  pdf.stroke_bounds
```

Your original code would look like this:

```
  pdf.bounding_box([200, pdf.cursor - 100], :width => 200, :height => 100) do
      pdf.text "Just your regular bounding box"
      pdf.stroke_bounds
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your issue. When you say

> the code will work, but I can't see the text box

do you mean that you can't see the box's borders, but you can still see the text? Or that you can't see the text either?
I would expect the former, since it is the `stroke_bounds` that causes the borders to be drawn.

So to answer your "what do I need to change", it depends on what you're trying to accomplish:

- if you need the text but don't need the box borders, you can remove the `pdf.transparent(0.5) { pdf.stroke_bounds }, whose only job is to draw a semi-transparent (i.e. gray) border around the bounding box
- if you want the border, leave that line in
- if you want the border, but want the height of the box to conform to the height of the text, then remove the `:height => 100` from the first line. The bounding_box height will then adjust to fit the text.